# How to position carousel-status in react-responsive-carousel?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-responsive-carousel

I am trying to move the status indicator to the bottom-right corner, but I cannot find the way to do it.

I have added statusFormatter and custom component within, but the problem is that react-responsive-carousel renders

element so I cannot apply margin and padding from the child span.

Is there a way to position the status indicator in the bottom-right corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the snippet to modify it, all you need to do is change css of the class `.carousel .carousel-status` which is assigned to status `<p>` tag:

```
.carousel .carousel-status {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

you can edit this snippet to suit you need.